# What does "WROOM" mean?

Tags: terminology, esp32

I see numerous references to ESP32-WROOM.

Does "WROOM" have a meaning, or is it just a marketing term for a particular version of the ESP32?

Comment: In before: I put my money on W for Wireless.

Comment: Given there is no any decryption for that in the open documentation, I would say it is a code name having some internal meaning but not for general public

Comment: Rest of my money goes to M for Module. To be fair Espressif who make these modules are a Chinese company who can be quite cryptic in their communication. So the acronym could be pretty wild for all I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, it's merely a part number in the ESP32 family of parts.  While there may be some hidden meaning, I suspect that it contains an English word to be a concidence.

Here is the set of ESP32 parts from Espressif Systems:

[ESP32 Series of Modules](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/modules/esp32)

[image: Module Comparison]

Comment: It is an intentional coincidence. Developers tend to first come up with a cool word for a code name, then trying to match some expansion to it. Probably in this case it was quite stupid to be revealed to the public